# how to implement same product of different weights

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know if this question should be here or not but i don't see any other place fit to ask my problem.

See, i am developing an online food portal which obviously sells food , snacks ,cakes and desserts.The real deal comes up when i have to sell a cake which can exist in various weights such as `0.1|0.5|0.9|...4.5` and every one of them costs different.Furthermore, every one of them are present in different quantities in warehouse.

My solution to achieve this was to provide a different row for every variant

```
ID | product_code | product name | Quantity | price | weight | company_id 
1  |  12345       | beer cake    |   34     |345    |0.5     |343434defee
2  |  12345       | beer cake    |   343    |600    |1.0     |343434defee
3  |  12345       | beer cake    |   4      |845    |1.5     |343434defee
4  |  12346       | vodka cake   |   341    |345    |0.5     |343434deereee
```

Here , i looked every product to be a different product,I provided the relation using product code while to differentitate every row , i choose `id,product_code` as the primary key.

But, using this method involves redudancy as well,  every row is looked as a different product.So if i were to display them using `php` it would show them as different product.

Something like this,

[image]

How do i change my structure of my database in order to achieve a single product but with different variants option on the same item?

I could use a `php` solution , if it's there.

Regards,

BOTjr.

Comment: The usual way is to introduce variants of products. You can either do it by adding a new table "variants"  (that just contain the product code and a variant code and the columns that may differ, like weight and price), or, a little more messy but still often used in online shop software, do it in the same table, define one product as the main one, and add a column that links to main product if it is a variant of that product. And you should consider calculating the quantity by using a stock table (where you insert all changes), one value will get you in trouble when you go live.

Comment: @Solarflare could you show an example?

Answer (score 3):

Split the table into two with `product_code` as foreign key.

```
Table One
    ID | product_code | product name | company_id 
    1  |  12345       | beer cake    |343434defee
    2  |  12346       | vodka cake   |343434deereee

Table Two
       Product_code |Quantity | price | weight 
       12345        |  34     |345    |0.5 
       12345        |  343    |600    |1.0 
       12345        |  4      |845    |1.5 
       12346        |  341    |345    |0.5
```

Use `Table One` to display items, Use `Table Two` is product description page to select the right quantity

Comment: Could you show a little php code to show how you would provide the options for the selection of various variants ?

Comment: Do you know to perform MySQL query in php?

Comment: lol, yea i do , leave it.I will see to it.Thanks for providing me a fair idea of how to do this thing.

Comment: execute one query for displaying items from table one, and after user clicks on one item execute another query to display its quatity/weight and price options